# Format of json file corresponding to database table

Tags: json

I am having XML file

```
  <society>
    <person>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
   <age>25</age>  
   <person>
    <firstName>Janelia</firstName>
    <lastName>Disouza</lastName>
   <age>20</age>  
   </person>
</society>
```

. I have to create a corresponding json file .How could i go for it .Needs suggestion / solutions .

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"MyTable": [
   { "Name":"Eric", "Age":23 }
   { "Name":"Adam", "Age":34 }
   { "Name":"Julie","Age":25 }
   ]
}
```

I guess, this is usefull for your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the json syntax on w3schools page: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

In your example it might be something like this:

```
{
  'society' : {
    'person' : [
      { 'firstName' : 'John', 'lastName' : 'Smith', 'age' : 25 },
      { 'firstName' : 'John', 'lastName' : 'Smith', 'age' : 20 }    
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure! :) Can you mark an answer as "answered this question" to show the other users that this question has a correct and helpful answer? Thanks